# How to Remove Last digit of String in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to eliminate B if i scan Serial number bar code: 21524116476CA2006765B

Output: 21524116476CA2006765

Comment: Do you really mean remove the last character regardless if it's a digit or not? Do you want to remove only Bs? Do you care if the string is null or empty first? What if the last character is not a letter? What if the code ends with multiple letters?

Comment: There is no such thing as C#.NET. There is C#, and there is VB.NET, and that's it.

Comment: @John Saunders: Is that important to this question? Not really. Also, it is called both interchangeably by people who crafted the language itself, as seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289528(VS.71).aspx

Comment: @byte: these questions and their answers are read by many people other than the OP and those who answered. I consider it important to not allow misinformation to persist here. SO is an important information to many developers - we should not permit it to become an important source of misinformation. One such piece of misinformation is is the link you posted - perhaps you didn't notice that's a Visual Studio 2003/.NET 1.1 link?

Comment: @John Saunders The version of Visual Studio is irrelevant to the discussion. If you want to get very technical about it, there is no such thing as VB.NET either, its simply a naming convention. The actual name for the language after VB6 continues the trend of version number, including VB 7.0, VB 8.0, VB 9.0, VB 10.0. Hence, the discussion of the naming of a language isn't really relevant or as important as the concept conveyed. I could just as easily point out that you are incorrect in stating "Visual Studio 2003". Don't you know that it's REALLY Visual Studio 7.1 ? Perhaps you see the point.

Comment: @byte: my point was that, .NET 1.1 is about seven years old, so the fact that you've found a .NET 1.1 article that uses the term doesn't mean much. If anyone from Microsoft called it "C#.NET", then they did so about seven years ago. If you have a more recent example, then please post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string foo = "21524116476CA2006765B";
string bar = foo.Substring(0, Math.Max(foo.Length - 1, 0));
```

Comment: Yup.
I only want to remove the letter B. or the last digit.
And i only want to capture the first 20 digit. ") Thanks for your replies. i will try it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't be certain that the input barcode will always end with a B, do something like this:

```
char[] barcodeEnd = { 'B' };

string input = "21524116476CA2006765B";
string output = input.TrimEnd(barcodeEnd);
```

PUt the first line somewhere it'll only get run once, so you aren't constantly creating new char[] arrays.  You can add more characters to the array if you're looking for other specific characters.

Comment: Yup.
I only want to remove the letter B. or the last digit.
And i only want to capture the first 20 digit. ") Thanks for your replies. i will try it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "21524116476CA2006765B";
string b = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string value= "21524116476CA2006765B";
string bar = value.Substring(0, 19);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "Your String Whatever it is";
str = str.Substring(0, s.Length - 1);
```